# Google Maps API V3 Marker Not Loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a marker to show on the google map for a website I am doing. Without the marker code the map loads fine and shows the correct location (with no marker), when I add the marker code the map no longer loads. Clearly I am missing something simple but I am not too familiar with Jquery.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWJYTBt3bKUIsQKKsQPSnR1IHNdkAmBQs&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.154662, -1.208357),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:(53.154662, -1.208357),
  map: map-canvas,
  title:"Hello World!"
});
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: "I am not too familiar with Jquery." You are not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map`-property is expected to be a `google.maps.Map`-instance and the position-property has to be a `google.maps.LatLng`:

Furthermore you must create the marker when the map already has been created and in a scope where the maps-instance is accessible, e.g. at the end of `initialize()`.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.154662, -1.208357),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:new google.maps.LatLng(53.154662, -1.208357),
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only changed it after I had the problem as I thought that could be the mistake. I have now changed it back to just "map" (without quotations) and it is still the same.

Comment: I have changed it to your posted code but the map still fails to load. If I comment out that section the map loads. Thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, it was that last } that was missing and causing the problem.

Comment: @Mooton, when this happens again, open the JavaScript console to see the error message. You don't have to let a syntax error stop you.